Sci-fi movie with robots controlling humans through the back of their necks
I saw a segment of a movie at a friend's house about 27 years ago.  What I remember:

There seemed to be a warehouse(?) where robots were kept;
There was some sort of robot uprising?
There was a scene where a robot with a masculine name picked up a main character woman by her wrists and was holding her up in the air;
A main character man tells the woman she needs to ask the robot (Harold? Howard?) to put her down, which she does (and the robot does);
There's another scene where the robots appear to be controlling the humans by inserting a needle into the backs of their necks and... ???

Not much to go on but there it is!

I think you're after Saturn 3 from 1980. The robot was called Hector.

In the future, Earth is overcrowded and the population relies on distant bases to be fed. In the Saturn 3 station, Major Adam and the scientist Alex, who is also his lover and has never been on Earth, have been researching hydroponics for three years in the base alone with their dog Sally. Meanwhile, the psychotic Captain Benson fails the mental test required to travel to Saturn 3 and kills his replacement, Captain James, taking his place in the mission of assembling and programming the Demi-God series robot Hector to replace one of the scientists in Saturn 3. On the arrival, the mentally disturbed Captain Benson becomes sexually obsessed for Alex. Then he uses an interface to link his brain to program Hector, but incapable to control his emotions, he transfers his homicidal tendency and insanity to Hector. Now Major Adam and Alex are trapped in the station with a dangerous psychopath robot. 

Benson (Harvey Keitel) can connect to Hector through the back of his neck. You can see the scene with Hector lifting the woman (Farrah Fawcett) by her wrists here:



